# Invalid regular expression: nothing to repeat Safari Console Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a code that works fine on other browsers but it doesn't work on iPhones and Safari browser. When I debug it says "Invalid regular expression: nothing to repeat" for the following code.

```
  function getURLParameter(a) {
    a = (new RegExp("[?|&]" + a + "=([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)")).exec(location.search);
    if (null == a) return null;
    a = a[1];
    a = a.replace(/+/g, "%20");
    return decodeURIComponent(a)
}
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does parameter `a` contains something like backslash? any input example for the parameter `a` would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't. The console says there is an error on  a = a.replace(/+/g, "%20"); line.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are [plenty of well-documented methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters) for getting URL parameters in JavaScript, including the native [`searchParams.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem come from `a = a.replace(/+/g, "%20");`, the `+` means repeat a character one or more times, but there's no character before it, if you want to replace "+" by "%20" you can simply call `a.replace("+", "%20")` or regex ver `a.replace(/\+/g, "%20")`

i'm sorry, `a.replace("+", "%20")` only replace the first "+", so you need `a.replace(/\+/g, "%20")` to replace all "+" by "%20"

Comment: This is correct; to elaborate, the `+` character has special meaning in regex. To treat it as the character `"+"`, you need to escape it using a backslash: `\+`. This is why the regex becomes `/\+/g`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarifying. I just tried it and still the issue remains. :( Strange thing is that it only occurs on safari and apple iphones.

Comment: you used `a.replace(/\+/g, "%20")` and the issue still remains? maybe the browser cached, make sure you cleared the caches

Comment: Sorry for the hassle. You were right! It was the cache. Tyvm!